# iterate over json array - how to get the name / key of collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get a json object from an API ; I'm getting (inside another collection - but that doesn't matter) a collection of keys like so:

```
{ "Id": "64a66e2c-38fa-41dd-9183-8b1bd18a3c87",
    "fields": [
        { "Name": "x1" },
        { "Name": "x2" },
        { "Name": "x3" }

    ],
    "weeks": [ "2015-25", "2015-26", "2015-27" ],
    "series": {
        "M1": [ 6376, 17877, 22592 ],
        "M2": [ 700, 702, 702 ],
        "M3": [ null, 1, 1 ],
        "M4": [ null, 5889, 10275 ]

    } 
}
```

the series itself (like M1) have values (1 - 1 etc) I can read and use,
but I actually need the name of the serie (like "M1").

So I iterate over the collection series and over each values within that serie without any difficulty, but how do I get the name of the serie itself - that name is (not in this example) quite descriptive and usefull

```
$.each(data.series, function (rowIndex, row) {
    var attempt = data.series[rowIndex]; // nope this is [1,1,1,2] or something
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        var value = row[i]; // yep this is one of the values
    };
});
```

how do I get "serie1" into `var attempt`?

Comment: Can you show the actual JSON rather than your current way of showing the structure?

Comment: As Your data has `seria1`, then `data.series` should be an `Object`, `$.each` can also apply on `Object`, while the function param becomes `key, value`, so, try to log out `rowIndex` in your code, that should be what you want.

Comment: There needs to be a new site to handle the dozens of questions like this that come in everyday: jsonoverflow

Comment: added the JSON not the structure

Comment: @George maybe what we need is something like JSON for Dummies :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already get the key as the first param when passing in a javascript object to the $.each() iterator.

```
$.each(data.series, function (rowIndex, row) {
    window.alert(rowIndex);
});
```

Comment: Lost in my own "should be a number" thought process - I completely overlooked this... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what everyone is trying to say is that a more descriptive signature of the jquery.each callback is:

```
$.each(data.series, function (key, val) {
    var attempt = data.series[key]; // nope this is [1,1,1,2] or something
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        var value = val[i]; // yep this is one of the values
    };
});
```

so to get what you want, simple change to:

```
$.each(data.series, function (key, val) {
    var attempt = key;
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        var value = val[i];
    };
});
```